# openwebrtc demo is not working in Chrome

Tags: webrtc, apprtcdemo, apprtc, openwebrtcdemo, openwebrtc

Chrome supports WebRTC.

But openwebrtc I am not able to run

http://demo.openwebrtc.org:38080/

while apprtc I am able to run

https://apprtc.appspot.com/

so *why this problem* ?

so *what is the difference between openwebrtc and apprtc* ?

*is there any different implementation in thes*e ?

I know both use WebRTC APIs

so my gut feeling is the demo sample that I use for openwebrtc is not https so chrome doesn’t let it access camera ,mike and so its not working.While Apprtc sample is https

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open web console:

> getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

This is a limitation in Chrome. The page works fine in, say, Firefox.

Comment: Yeah thanks for sharing the reference link.My gut feeling about this issue is right then !!!

Comment: Hi,I went through your answers...I saw you have made a great contribution in WEBRTC...so I welcome you to be part of this chat-group http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103269/webrtc