# getUserMedia error:Failed to get access to local media - WEBRTC

Tags: webrtc, apprtcdemo, simplewebrtc, apprtc

I've configured the App RTC Server in my PC. When I am accessing using local host ([localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000)). The Video call is working. But when I am using IP address getting the error. (http://192.168.0.103:3000)

> Failed to get access to local media. Error name was
>   PermissionDeniedError. Continuing without sending a stream.
>
> Error getting user media. Only secure origins are allowed.
>   getUsermedia error: Failed to get access to local media.

Comment: Starting with Chrome 47, getUserMedia() requests are only allowed from secure origins: HTTPS or localhost.
You can setup a self signed ssl certificate for the local webserver and then you can access with `https://192.168.0.103:<https port>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openwebrtc demo is not working in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359138/openwebrtc-demo-is-not-working-in-chrome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getUserMedia`needs HTTPS to work. You'll have to implement HTTPS for your webserver. `localhost` is the only domain allowed to use `getUserMedia` without HTTPS.